# Invalid Bundle App Store Connect Operation Error in validation - Xcode 13

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am doing my first validation with React Native 0.68 app/MacOS 10.15 and here is the error thrown out in validation.

```
App Store Connect Operation Error
Invalid Bundle. iPad Multitasking support requires these orientations: 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight'. Found 'UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft,UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight' in bundle 'com.mydomain.xyz.app6'.
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

iPad Multitasking support requires all the orientations but your app does not, so you need to opt out of it, just add the `UIRequiresFullScreen` key to your Xcode project’s **Info.plist** file and apply the Boolean value `YES`.

OR

In Xcode, check the "Requires Full Screen" checkbox under General > Targets, as shown below.

[image]